# Android Studio prevent import statements wrapping

Tags: android, android-studio

I used Android Studio wrapping feature to ensure code does not exceed 120 characters. This works fine for almost anything, but Android Studio keeps wrapping import statements which is ugly. I would instead prefer to say to Android Studio to never wrap import statements.

current:

```
import com.acme.projet.ui.very.long.package.name
  .InstallationCoreFeatureActivity;
import com.acme.projet.ui.very.long.package.name
  .InstallationSelectorActivity;
import com.acme.projet.ui.very.long.package
  .InstallationOtherFeatureActivity;
```

wanted:

```
import com.acme.projet.ui.very.long.package.name.InstallationCoreFeatureActivity;
import com.acme.projet.ui.very.long.package.name.InstallationSelectorActivity;
import com.acme.projet.ui.very.long.package.InstallationOtherFeatureActivity;
```

Does anybody know if it's possible and if possible, how to achieve this?

Edit: To crazy reviewer/editer, the wrapping in the current code example is done on purpose.

Comment: @Ricardo Vieira the edit is wrong, it was made on purpose to show the wrapping performed by Android Studio, I can I revert the edit?

Comment: Hey @Matt. Yeah sure! I thought otherwise. My bad!

Comment: Hehe no problem :)

Comment: Just out of interest, why such a low limit? 120 characters goes quick.

Comment: We agreed as team to stick to that for now but this has been debated and may change, but probably never beyond 140~150 so one line fit entirely on our work screens. The problem would be less apparent of course with an higher limit, but I hope we agree, still remains :)